# Display XML Reference with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" standalone="no"?>
    <?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="bookstorex.xsl"?>
    <company>
        <bookstore>
            <standort1 standort-id="h_1"></standort1>
            <standort2 standort-id="h_2"></standort2>
        </bookstore>
        <book_list>
            <book category="cooking" book-id="b_1" standort-id="h_1">
                <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
                <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
                <year>2005</year>
                <price>30.00</price>
            </book>
            <book category="children" book-id="b_2" standort-id="h_2">
                <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
                <author>J K. Rowling</author>
                <year>2005</year>
                <price>29.99</price>
            </book>
        </book_list>
    </company>
```

This is the XSL im using at the moment:

```
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:template match="book_list">
            <html>
                <body>
                    <h1>Mein Bookstore</h1>
                    <table border = "2">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Bookname</th>
                            <th>Author</th>
                            <th>Year</th>
                            <th>price</th>
                        </tr>
                        <xsl:for-each select = "book">
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "title"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "author"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "year"/>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <xsl:value-of select = "price"/>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </xsl:for-each>
                    </table>
                </body>
            </html>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Yo how can i display the books of standort1 inside a html table with XSLT?
At the moment im only able to simply display all books but i want to use id/idref to make a list for different bookstores

Comment: While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) Input XML.
(2) Your logic, and XSLT that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its compliance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, or 3.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to resolve cross-references. Here's an example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:key name="book-by-location" match="book" use="@standort-id"/>

<xsl:template match="/company">
    <html>
        <body>
            <xsl:for-each select="bookstore/*">
                <h1>
                    <xsl:text>Location </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@standort-id"/>
                </h1>
                <table border="2">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Bookname</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                        <th>Year</th>
                        <th>price</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('book-by-location', @standort-id)">
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="author"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <xsl:value-of select="price"/>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```